# Sending multiple dynamic fields with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

We need to send a POST request to a web service that needs dynamic multiple fields.

I mean, we need to send something like this as POST request:

```
question1='answer1'&question2='answer1'&question2='answer2'&question3='answer1'
```

where question1 and question2 are not set in compilation time. We know that we can use a @FieldMap for using dynamic fields, but we cannot send the same field more than one time.

This is our Retrofit code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/desafios/send/")
Observable<BaseServerMsgArray> postSubmitSurvey(@Field("customerId") Long customerId, @Field("upload_from_app") int uploadFromApp, @FieldMap HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashFields);
```

Could anyone help us?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can send a json string  as argument in instead of field map

Answer (score 8):

Prepare HashMap like below, put only those questaion that user answered.

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("question1", answer1);
 map.put("question2", answer2);
 map.put("question3", answer3);
```

change your retrofit as below

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/desafios/send/")
Observable<BaseServerMsgArray> postSubmitSurvey(@Field("customerId") Long customerId, @Field("upload_from_app") int uploadFromApp, @FieldMap HashMap<String, String> hashFields);
```

and pass above HashMap as last argument

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not my question. I need to send more than one "question2" value.

Comment: If you need to send more than one `question2` value..then it sounds like you need an array...something that would get converted into `question2[]=$MY_FIRST_ARRAY_VAL&question2[]=$MY_SECOND_ARRAY_VAL`.. have you tried passing a hashmap with String keys and a String[]..or a List?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the output format does not match, it has a list separated by commas. Thank you.

Comment: @Juzmulti have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a map that can contain duplicate keys. Unfortunately there is no such map in standard Android. You might use this onehttps://github.com/greenrobot/essentials/blob/master/java-essentials/src/main/java/org/greenrobot/essentials/collections/Multimap.java

If this won't work, try to manually convert your questions to String and send properly formatted String.